# Is there a way I can double the punishment when model mis-classing to a specific class?

Tags: classification, loss-function, multiclass-classification, overfitting, loss

As the title I asked.

For example: a model that predicts the probability of a stock price rising/falling. Let's say this is a triple-classification problem.

If it predicts "RISING", while the truth is "NO CHANGE", I want to give it a normal loss result;

If it predicts "RISING", but the truth is **"FALLING"**, I want to give it more loss result.

How to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it would be good for you to know the reason for mis-classing, usually
the reason is that data are imbalanced, so you should look at targert class distribution.

Depending on the model you can use some regularization technique or assign weights to the desired class, for example in sklearn with decision tree.

```
# class 1 with weight 0, so clf only predicts class 0                         
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, class_weight={0: 1, 1: 0})
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using a GRU model built with pytorch.
I have resolved the imbalance of the classes by randomly abandon negtive sample.
Would you pls give some hint about RNN/GRU liked model?

Comment: I can't give you any specific tips, as I know little about gru, I've only used lstm once, but I recommend to use a hyperparameter optimizer like optuna (I currently use this one) or hyperopt. Then you could test different hyperparameters including the regularization.